# LOA due to chronic insomnia, stress, depression, and DDD, chronic pain

Tags: stress, leave-of-absence, depression

I dont know if this question has been asked already, probably so. Due to the , mentioned above, Ive had chronic insomnia for years, resistant to anti depressants and sleep meds, from my psychiatrist. i no longer see him him, no sense in it now. Been to a pain specialist for back problems and chronic pain, who recently got jailed and suspended.  Needless to say im very depressed and stressed. Lack of sleep and 12 hour swing shifts are just too much anymore.  Ive worked and am currently working at my company for 13 years. But latley, due to all this and more i have 44 hours of FMLA left, then i lose my job. I NEED to know if and or how to get a LOA for the above mentioned. All conditions mentioned were diagnosed by physicians. im in the U.S.A. Indiana. I CANT lose my job.

Comment: Sorry to see that it looks like you are in a bad place, and hope someone can help you. It may help you get a valid answer if you give the location of your employment (country/state), plus any official status your conditions have - i.e. have you been assessed in any way for any of them by a medical professional and have some form of *current* documented proof of them?

Comment: yes. all mentioned were diagnosed by specialists. Have also had 2 sleep studies. Which they couldnt find anything cause i couldnt sleep. And the DDD cant be cured, only treated with pain meds, which dont work well and make me even more tired......im screwed huh?

Comment: "I have 44 hours of FMLA left, then i lose my job."  How do you know this?  Did your employer tell you so?

Comment: ofcourse FMLA is a Federal plan for medical leave taken. Your alotted so many hours and once they are used up. ur done.

Comment: You need to find a resource that's capable of sorting through this situation with you and providing personalised advice. That's not what this site is for.

Comment: Also, are you talking about a paid or unpaid leave of absence (LOA)?

Comment: What is DDD anyway?

Comment: unpaid... degenerative disc disease

Answer (score 3):

So you are explaining that you would rather suffer in pain and depression and less income than see a psychiatrist and take medication to possibly alleviate the actual issues?

I don't know your specific scenario here but anyone who is suffering from depression, stress, and insomnia (or any single one of those) and actively chooses to stop treatment and deny medication is going to down a dark path of their own doing.

I understand that part of the struggle of depression is the fact that it makes you not want to seek help, but you are here and aware enough to know that where you are currently in your life is not healthy. The unfortunate part is that you seem to believe that time off from work will somehow cure these things. You have to understand that is just not possible. If time off from work were any kind of cure for depression or other psychological disorders the world would be a very different place.

Finding the right medications is also a very long road to take, but at least you have the added benefit of actively seeking treatment under the care of a professional and not just shooting in the dark hoping doing nothing, rather than something, will help.

In my opinion, you should only take time off to *actively* pursue treatment, not passively. If you find a doctor and create a care plan, you are much more likely to get a LOA than if you simply state that your mental health is failing but do not have any doctor to back it up and no actual reason as to why leaving work will benefit you.

Companies only want to give a LOA if you provide some type of incentive to keep you on. If they don't feel like you will return as the productive employee that you are, why would they want to hold your position while you "seek health" knowing you aren't actually seeking *treatment*?

Comment: this is already what i stated. Ive been diagnosed and am still currently under a doctors care. As for depression, as stated, i am resistant to the meds.....

Comment: And none said i was stopping treatment. where do u ppl read that at?

Comment: @DarrenH: You say in your question that you are no longer seeing the psychiatrist or pain specialist, and do not state who you currently *are* seeing or what you are doing. Perhaps for clarity you should add what you are currently doing to the question, because it does read as if you have given up on all current treatments - or simply that they are not working and you feel the only hope of recovery is extended rest.

Comment: *anyone who is suffering from depression, stress, and insomnia (or any single one of those) and actively chooses to stop treatment and deny medication is going to down a dark path of their own doing* That bullocks, mate. It's a perfectly legitimate choice, which does not always result in disaster.

Answer (score 2):

> But latley, due to all this and more i have 44 hours of FMLA left,
>   then i lose my job. I NEED to know if and or how to get a LOA for the
>   above mentioned.

You might choose to investigate if you qualify for an accommodation under the ADA.

Most likely, you'll need to continue to be treated professionally, in order to get a physician to certify your continued incapacity to work. There are treatments for depression other than just medication.

If you haven't, you should talk with your HR department to see where you stand, and what they plan to do once your FMLA leave is exhausted.

You indicate that "due to all this *and more*" you are concerned that you will lost your job. It's not clear what *and more* means in this context, but perhaps that's the more significant issue that you want to discuss with HR.

If the company thinks you have been abusing the FMLA (I'm not saying you have), then many will choose to dismiss you if you don't return to work. So it's best to find out *now* from HR what they plan, and what they have done with others in the past. That will give you an idea of what you must do going forward.

Comment: I agree with this. Your company can't fire you because you are protected under FMLA. As soon as you run out of time on that, you BET they are going to try to get rid of you. I think your best bet would be investigating protection under the ADA first (that might slow your employer down) then look into getting onto some sort of state / government disability. I don't see other options besides miraculous recovery. You could also try to find another job where you can stretch out the clock a bit more, state/govt jobs as well tend to have better protections for employees' medical conditions.